# How to set multiple 'active' classes from query string

Tags: search, tags, css, querystring

I'm outputting all tags that are in use and then allowing the user to click these build up a query string to filter and display the results. It's all working fine.

Except, I'm having difficulty understanding what can I use to set an 'active' class on all the selected tags that are being added to the query string.

Setting 1 tag as active is simple enough, but when multiple are selected, I'm not so sure.

The URL looks like this: `domain.com/learning/resources?tags=Video+Maths`

Setting tags via getParam:

```
{% set tags = craft.request.getParam('tags') %}
```

Listing all tags in use like this:

```
{% set resourceTags = craft.entries.section('resources').limit(null) %}
{% for tag in craft.tags.relatedTo(resourceTags) %}
```

Outputting results like this:

```
{% craft.entries.section('resources').limit(craft.config.paginateLimit).search(tags) as entries %}`
```

Comment: I'm still having trouble with this. Is tags and search the wrong way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps not the most elegant solution, but this works:

```
{% set queryTags = craft.request.getQuery('tags') %}

{% for tag in craft.tags.relatedTo(resourceTags) %}
   <a
     href="{% if tags == "" %}/learning/resources?tags={{ tag.title|kebab }}{% else %}/learning/resources?tags={{ tags|replace(' ', '+') }}+{{ tag.title|kebab }}{% endif %}"
     class="btn btn-default{% if tag.title|kebab in queryTags %} disabled{% endif %}"
   >{{ tag.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Adding `disabled` rather than `active`.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to create an array of tag ids for tags that should be active.

I would use a comma to separate multiple tags in your query string since the browser interprets a plus sign as a space. For example, if your tags were "New Videos" and "Maths" the url would look like this:

`domain.com/learning/resources?tags=New+Videos,Maths`

First, get the "tags" query parameter and make an array splitting each tag at a comma:

```
{% set tagsQuery = craft.app.request.getParam('tags')|split(',') %}

{# tagsQuery = ["New Videos","Maths"] #}
```

Search your tag group for matching titles and return an array of ids. This assumes you have a tag group with the handle "tags":

```
{% set activeTags = tagsQuery ? craft.tags.group('tags').title(tagsQuery).ids() : null %}
```

Then it's a simple matter of testing if the tag.id is in the activeTags array.

```
{% for tag in craft.tags.relatedTo(resourceTags) %}
  {{ tag.title }}

  {# Use a conditional #}
  {% if item.id in activeTags %}active{% endif %}

  {# or an output tag with a conditional #}
  {{ item.id in activeTags ? 'active' }}
{% endfor %}
```